# EF - default values for related entities in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have read various answers that indicate that it good practice to use the constructor of an entity to provide default property values, thus:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCool { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        this.IsCool = true;
    }
}
```

However, if you initialize a navigation property...

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCool { get; set; }
    public Child { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        this.IsCool = false;
        this.Child = new Child();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
        this.Age = 13;
    }
}
```

... then even when I explicitly load a Child thus:

```
var parent = db.Parents.Include(p => p.Child).FirstOrDefault();
```

parent.Child is set to a new instance of Child (Id = 0, Age = 13), which is not desired.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't initialize Navigation Properties in the constructor as it will override materialized EF data from the database.

If you need to make sure `Child` is initialized (so you won't get `NullReferenceException` thrown at you). You can use backing-fields:

```
// Navigation Property
public Child Child
{
    get { return this.i_Child ?? (this.i_Child = new Child()); }
    set { this.i_Child = value; }
}

// Backing Field
protected internal virtual ContactDetails i_ContactDetails { get; private set; }
```

No need for any special mapping, Entity Framework will automatically detect the backing-field and it's wrapper and will act almost as if there's no backing-field at all (but the column name in the database will be the same of the backing-field, unless you explicitly name it).

Comment: Presumably you'd need to be pretty careful to ensure that the backing field is always loaded from the DB before trying to access the Child property?