# Property Entity data not being loaded

Tags: entity-framework

I'm studying Entity Framework and using Code First and Data Annotations.

My problem, is when trying to get the data, the data for the related property is not being loaded (i.e all values are always 0)

Below is my code:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key()]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Price")]
    public int PriceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductID = 0;
        this.Name = String.Empty;
        this.Price = new Price();
        this.IsActive = true;
    }


public class Price
{
    [Key()]
    public int PriceID { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }


    public Price()
    {
        this.PriceID = 0;
        this.CostPrice = 0.00m;
        this.RetailPrice = 0.00m;
    }
}
```

Here's the code to get the data by ID:

```
    public Product Get(int ID)
    {
        Product output = null;

        using (PrismContext context = new PrismContext())
        {

            output = context.Products.Include("Price")
                        .Where(p => p.ProductID == ID)
                        .FirstOrDefault();


            return output;
        }
    }
```

I'm able to get the data from the properties for the Product object, but the Price is always 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're initializing `Price` in the `Product` constructor.

Remove this line:

```
this.Price = new Price();
```

Also, the `Price` constructor is completely redundant as it initialize the properties to its  default values.

Comment: Are you sure that's true?  I would think EF would first instantiate `Product` and then use it's `Price` property to set the price.

Comment: Yes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836194/ef-default-values-for-related-entities-in-constructor

Comment: hi haim thanks very much, removing it fixed the problem. Also removed the default values from the constructors